# How to implement adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta

Trying to implement an adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp but failing with this error:

```
home/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:15: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

The ODE i am trying to solve (and using in the example below, transformed from higher order to system of 1st order ODEs) is the following:

[image: 2nd order ODE to be transformed in system of two 1st order ODEs]

Here is the implementation I am using:

```
def rkck(f, x, y, h, tol):
    #xn = x + h
    err = 2 * tol
    while (err > tol):
        xn = x + h
        k1 = h*f(x,y)
        k2 = h*f(x+(1/5)*h,y+((1/5)*k1)) 
        k3 = h*f(x+(3/10)*h,y+((3/40)*k1)+((9/40)*k2))
        k4 = h*f(x+(3/5)*h,y+((3/10)*k1)-((9/10)*k2)+((6/5)*k3))
        k5 = h*f(x+(1/1)*h,y-((11/54)*k1)+((5/2)*k2)-((70/27)*k3)+((35/27)*k4))
        k6 = h*f(x+(7/8)*h,y+((1631/55296)*k1)+((175/512)*k2)+((575/13824)*k3)+((44275/110592)*k4)+((253/4096)*k5))
        yn4 = y + ((37/378)*k1)+((250/621)*k3)+((125/594)*k4)+((512/1771)*k6)
        yn5 = y + ((2825/27648)*k1)+((18575/48384)*k3)+((13525/55296)*k4)+((277/14336)*k5)+((1/4)*k6)
        err = yn4[-1]-yn5[-1]
        if (err != 0):
            h = 0.8 * h * (tol/err)**(1/float(5))
        yn = yn4
    return xn, yn

def integrate_sStepControl(f, t0, y0, tend, h, tol):
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0 
    while (t < tend):
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y = rkck(f, t, y, h, tol)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)

def f_1(t,y): 
    return np.array([ y[1], -y[0]-(y[0])**3 ])

Y0_f1 = np.array([1.0,1.0])


# Execution
h = 0.05
tv, yv = integrate_sStepControl(f=f_1, t0=0.0, y0=Y0_f1, tend=100.0, h=h, tol=1.0E-05)
print("[ %20.15f, %20.15f]"%(yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]) )
plt.plot(tv, yv)
```

Getting the error above, but it gets plotted. Don't know what I am doing wrong here :-/ 
[image: plot]

EDIT:
Added check for err == 0

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Comment: You could put in a check for `err == 0 ` before trying to divide by it.

Comment: Okay. But besides that, what do you think of the implementation? Is it right?

Comment: If err == 0 then you don't need to calculate `h` because the while loop will exit and `h` won't be needed any more. As for the implementation, I don't know, but a good start would be to check the result against a known result.

Comment: You do not pass the computed value of `h` back to the main loop, so this computation is thrown away. You also need to avoid negative values of `err`, you can have both by setting `err=1e-40+norm(y4-y5)`. // Please indicate cross-postings of the question to avoid duplicated answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to actually pass back the computed new step size `h` so that it can be used in the main loop for the first step.

The error should be computed as norm. Add some small number to avoid division by zero.

The leading error term is `C*h^5` for the 4th order method. This has to be compared to the desired local error `tol*h`. In total that results in a 4th root to compute the optimal `h`. Taking the 5th root provides some kind of dampening, however the effect on the global error is not quite straight-forward.

```python
def rkck(f, x, y, h, tol):
    #xn = x + h
    err = 2 * tol
    while (err > tol):
        xn = x + h
        k1 = h*f(x,y)
        k2 = h*f(x+(1/5)*h,y+((1/5)*k1)) 
        k3 = h*f(x+(3/10)*h,y+((3/40)*k1)+((9/40)*k2))
        k4 = h*f(x+(3/5)*h,y+((3/10)*k1)-((9/10)*k2)+((6/5)*k3))
        k5 = h*f(x+(1/1)*h,y-((11/54)*k1)+((5/2)*k2)-((70/27)*k3)+((35/27)*k4))
        k6 = h*f(x+(7/8)*h,y+((1631/55296)*k1)+((175/512)*k2)+((575/13824)*k3)+((44275/110592)*k4)+((253/4096)*k5))
        dy4 = ((37/378)*k1)+((250/621)*k3)+((125/594)*k4)+((512/1771)*k6)
        dy5 = ((2825/27648)*k1)+((18575/48384)*k3)+((13525/55296)*k4)+((277/14336)*k5)+((1/4)*k6)
        err = 1e-2*tol+max(abs(dy4-dy5))
        # h = 0.95 * h * (tol/err)**(1/5)
        h = 0.8 * h * (tol*h/err)**(1/4)
        yn = y+dy4
    return xn, yn, h

def integrate_sStepControl(f, t0, y0, tend, h, tol):
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0 
    while (t < tend):
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y, h = rkck(f, t, y, h, tol)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)
```

With that your example gives the following plots for solutions, time steps and error/tol

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Very detailled and couldn't get better! You really helped me understand my error! Don't know how I can thank you more for what you're doing for the scientific community here!